# Context manager decorator never runs __exit__ if setUp fails inside test

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-decorators, contextmanager, django-unittest

I'm trying to solve a [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29024) in django. The bug involves a class called `TextContextDecorator` which can be used a class decorator and/or context manager.

As the bug description mentions, when using `TextContextDecorator` as class decorator `enable` is called just before `Test.setUp`, and `disable` is called after `Test.tearDown`.unfortunately, `tearDown` is not called in the event of a failure inside `setUp`. This can result in unexpected behaviour.

One of the proposed solutions is that to use `addCleanUp` inside the `setUp` of `TestContextDecorator`, but I'm having difficulties in calling that function inside of decorator class.

Here is the sample code provided to reproduce the bug..

```
class example_decorator(TestContextDecorator):
    some_var = False

    def enable(self):
        self.__class__.some_var = True

    def disable(self):
        self.__class__.some_var = False

class Example1TestCase(TestCase):
    def test_var_is_false(self):
        # some_var will be False
        self.assertFalse(example_decorator.some_var)


@example_decorator()
class Example2TestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        raise Exception

    def test_var_is_true(self):
        # won't be hit due to exception in setUp
        self.assertTrue(example_decorator.some_var)


class Example3TestCase(TestCase):
    def test_var_is_false(self):
        # some_var will be True now due to no cleanup in Example2TestCase
        self.assertFalse(example_decorator.some_var)
```

So far i have used `try` and `except` inside the `setUp` of  `TestContextDecorator` and that seems to solve the bug but i'm not sure if its the best way to do it. Here are the changes i [made](http://dpaste.com/1MYKGR3) (i have added `try` and `except` on line 30 of code provided in the link).

**Question**: What would be the correct way to run a function similar to `tearDown` in the event of failure inside `setUp` of Test when in a context manager? Is the `try` and `except` method that i used correct? or can we actually use `addCleanup` inside of `setUp` of `TestContextDecorator`?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of `example_decorator`.  Also: Did you have a question?

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. Please have a look at my edited question.